# Is it possible to build a Static SPA with Next.js that has dynamic routes?

Tags: next.js, single-page-application, dynamic-routing

I'm looking to build a static Next.js Single Page App that has dynamic routes, for example: `/posts/123`. I'd like to do this to:

- Be able to host the site anywhere (e.g. S3)
- Not need to know the routes at build time (so our APIs can change whenever independently of the Frontend/without requiring a rebuild of the Frontend)

From what I can tell, this *should* work with:

- `next build && next export`
- `fallback: true`

But [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages) suggest that's only for loading/intermediate states.

Can I use some combination of fallback pages/catchall dynamic routes/static generation to get a static single-page app with dynamic routes at runtime? I'm okay with faking the routes using nginx (e.g. `/posts/123` -> `/index.html`).

Edit: the above paragraph doesn't seem possible. From [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true), when using a required catchall route, e.g. `[...post].js`):

> `fallback: true` is not supported when using `next export`.

Comment: If you don't need SEO, it's better to use CRA

Comment: We'd like to avoid plugging our own SSR as well though, wouldn't CRA be more of a "batteries not included" approach?

Comment: Found any solution yet? I'm still looking for one.
I'd want to keep Nextjs instead of CRA for SEO benefits.
But i'd also want to be able to export a copy of the same app as an SPA to deploy it elsewhere.