# Is there a way to run a Next.js site with webpack (or `next dev`) without using node?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

## The problem

To clarify the question a bit, if I run `next dev`, and I have this code:

```js
window.localStorage.getItem('myCat')
```

I'll get an error like:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I'd like to run *some* kind of live reloaded dev environment.

## Solved in prod, but not in dev

A workable production solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231900/is-it-possible-to-build-a-static-spa-with-next-js-that-has-dynamic-routes) is:

1. Avoid [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)/`getStaticPaths`
2. `next build && next export`
3. Use nginx rewrite rules to rewrite `/some/route` to -> `/some/[dynamic].html`
4. Next.js handles the rest for us, even though we're serving the site completely statically (dynamic routes @ runtime, yay!)

## Summary

This question is simply the dev version of that issue: how can we get live reload + a static Next.js site? I know this isn't officially supported... but since we got it to work in prod I thought someone with more webpack knowledge might be able to point me in the right direction here.

## What I've tried

I thought I could use a combination of these tools:

- [custom webpack config for next](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config): used for multiple things below

  - [shim the window object](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7112#issuecomment-703187668) (that assumes we're still running node, but I've also tried [window-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-shim))
- [a custom next.js dev server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), but that doesn't seem to have any options that would help me... looks like I could do some URL rewriting like in their example, but I could use the next.config.js webpack config I mentioned above [for that](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) too

Comment: Is the question only about getting access to localStorage? If so, it should work without window, just use localStorage.getItem() etc.

Comment: Nope, sorry if it's confusing, it's about running a frontend-only static Next.js site in dev

Answer (score 0):

Next.js runs on the server, so it requires node.

It pre-renders the pages on the server. When you try to access the `window` API in your code running on the server, you get the error.

The solution is to run the client-side code only on client side. You can use React's `useEffect` hook for that. Or (as a quick workaround) just check if `window` is defined.

If this code is supposed to render smth, you can render null or some placeholder on the server and the actual content on the client.

Here's a nice article on this: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/

Comment: I know this isn't _officially_ supported, but we got it to work in prod! So I was hoping a webpack wizard might have some answers to how to live reload a client-side only version. We were able to use [webpack-strip-blocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-blocks) to solve some of the issue at build-time, but were hoping we wouldn't have to decorate the whole codebase with those (we just used them to remove SSR-only fns).